# setInterval() keeps Node.js process running

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm writing something like a token bucket in CoffeeScript.

```
class TokenBucket
  constructor: (@speed, @threshold) ->
    @currentVolume = 0
    @interval = setInterval =>
      @currentVolume += 1
      if @threshold < @currentVolume
        @currentVolume = @threshold
    , @speed * 1000

  stop: ->
    clearInterval @interval
    return

  get: ->
    if @currentVolume == 0
      false
    else
      @currentVolume -= 1
      true
```

For people not comfortable with CoffeeScript, let me simply explain this. After constructing a `TokenBucket`, it calls `setInterval` with a callback that increments the "bucket" every few seconds.

The problem is, if the user forgets to call `stop` before existing, the `setInterval` is going to keep the Node.js process running, because the event loop will never be empty. What I want to do is to tell Node.js that this `setInterval` in not important, you can terminate it if everything else is done. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you describe what node should "see" or what happens codepath wise for node to terminate the process without a user-initiated `stop` call?

Comment: "What I want to do is to tell Node.js that this setInterval in not important". What does "important" mean in this context?

Comment: Why don't you call `clearInterval` yourself when "everything else is done"?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans would be good to stop executing the callback in `setInterval()` and exit

Comment: @Vohuman it's kinda saying that this is only a coroutine, if the everyone else is done in the event loop, then stop executing this again and again.

Comment: @meskobalazs that would be good. but there are times I forget. and i'm actually building a module for a library. So can't expect the user to be that conformant. would be good if it can automatically do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What I want to do is to tell Node.js that this setInterval in not important, you can terminate it if everything else is done. How can I achieve that?

You are looking for the [`unref` method](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_unref), which "*will allow you to create a timer that is active but if it is the only item left in the event loop won't keep the program running.*".

```
class TokenBucket
  constructor: (@speed, @threshold) ->
    …
    @interval = setInterval =>
      …
    , @speed * 1000
    @interval.unref()
```

---

However, I wonder whether that is the best solution. Probably it would be better to make `@curretnVolume` a getter that dynamically computes its value (depending on the current time) only when needed. Something like

```
class TokenBucket
  constructor: (@speed, @threshold) ->
    @_start = Date.now()

  Object.defineProperty @::, "currentVolume",
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get: ->
      dt = (Date.now() - @_start) / 1000
      Math.min @threshold, Math.floor dt/@speed

  get: ->
    if @currentVolume == 0
      false
    else
      @_start = Math.max @_start, Date.now()-@threshold*@speed*1000 # not 100% accurate
      @_start += @peed*1000
      true
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Also, I agree with you it's better to compute its value when needed. That involves timestamp of last query and so on, right?

Comment: @Hot.PxL: Yeah, right. The decrease in `get()` does make it a bit complicated, though. I don't know your exact use case / problem domain so you might need/want to adapt it a bit, but I guess you'll figure it out.

Comment: I've been using Nodejs for years and had never seen this function before. Awesome.